# Best available worker instead of round-robin

Tags: rabbitmq

I've implemented a work queue based on `rabbitmq` example 2 with `qos` and `ack`. Everything works fine even the jobs priorities.

But jobs itself are very dependant on data locality. For example, I've got these servers:

1. worker1 with storage
2. worker2 with storage
3. worker3 without storage
4. worker3 without storage

The jobs are referring to data stored on workers with storages, for example

```
{ 
   job_id: 1,
   data: "worker2/pool5/dataset7"
}
```

I need to have this message dispatched to `worker2` if it's available, otherwise it should be dispatched to next available worker. 
So basically I need some router configuration which could respect data locality.

What should I use?

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, it would be good to know what you mean by "if it's available"

Answer (score 0):

There is sort of a fundamental assumption when consuming from a particular queue that all workers consuming from the queue are identical - same code, same hardware, etc.  When this assumption is violated, you'll have introduced some controllable variability into your system, and variability generally translates into instability and poor results.

Thus, I think for your purpose, you have two possible solution paths:

1. Change the consumers so that they are identical, including identical access to any particular storage, or
2. Create a different queue for each non-identical consumer, and update your routing logic to ensure that only appropriate messages end up in each queue.

Beyond this, there's some vague notion of "if the worker is not available" - I'm not sure what that means. There are many notions of "availability" in RabbitMQ, and while the broker can deal with many of them, it is generally considered bad design practice for the publisher to need to know exactly when and how each message is consumed.  If you could offer some clarification there, I could update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the answer.

By "worker not available" i meant "all workers on this server is busy processing jobs".

> Create a different queue for each non-identical consumer, and update your routing logic to ensure that only appropriate messages end up in each queue.

The only problem the producer does not know is worker is available (able to process jobs).

I'll try to explain.

We have a bunch of servers each contains large amount of data.
The amount of data to process by one job is big, from 100Gb to several Tb per job, so it's not very fast to stream them even over 10Gb network.

Right now all our workers is equal and consuming jobs from one queue, using qos and ack, using network shares.

So we are thinking to prioritise workers which can process data without streaming it.